# Rsync from Linux to Windows producing problems with back slash

Tags: windows, linux, rsync

I know if I was having an issue with rsync with characters I'd use --iconv= - but this issue is some file names have black slashes in them, and I don't have the ability to rename the original files.

Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: Using rsync under cygwin on Windows 7.

Comment: you mean... files in the linux fs have a "\" in the filename? ... this won't go well into windows... as the "\" character cannot exist in NTFS filenames.

Comment: How are you doing it? E.g. is Windows fs mounted via Samba, or are you using some Windows Rsync port?

Comment: @TheCompWiz - Of course.

Comment: @haimg - I'm using rsync under cygwin.

Comment: @TheCompWiz: Technically it can. It cannot exist in Win32 filenames regardless of the filesystem, but NTFS allows it.

Comment: @grawity If you're using NTFS in a posix environment... you have bigger issues.  That being said, For this to work, you'll have to parse the filename some other way.  Perhaps by encode the reserved characters '"' '*' '/' ':' '<' '>' '?' '\' '|' using urlencode or some such.

Comment: @TheCompWiz - How would I go about doing so?

Comment: Honestly, I wouldn't allow files written to disk with funny characters.  Or when commiting them to disk... renaming to something more appropriate.  But now that you're stuck...  Depending on the windows side of things... if you're using cygwin + rsync... just upgrade to cygwin 1.7+ which does correctly support utf8 with the invalid characters.  Or, rename the files on the linux side prior to the rsync.

Comment: @TheCompWiz - I'm using cygwin version 1.7.7.  As I said, I'm unable to rename the files on the Linux side.

Comment: what is preventing you from renaming the file?

Comment: @TheCompWiz part of a public site where data-base is dependent on it.  There are obviously alternatives, but they're far from simple ones, and I was hoping there'd be one for this particular case, since after all, my only issue is backups on my local Windows machine.